# The character table of $G/Z(G)$ and $G/N$ given knowledge of the character table of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, characters

Suppose for a group $G$, of which we completely understand its conjugacy class structure and character table, is there a simple algorithm to deduce the character table of $G/Z(G)$? Or more generally, $G/N$ for $N \trianglelefteq G$?

Comment: [Restricted representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_representation), [Clifford theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_theory)

Comment: @Shaun The question is intentionally isolated and general - this could come up in many different contexts.

Comment: I also believe the question is clearly motivated to anyone who knows character theory. Let's not close questions just because they're short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "yes". You can identify the columns of the character table of $G$, which correspond to elements in $N$. Then you take only those characters $\chi$, which have $\chi(1)=\chi(g)$ for every $g\in N$. This gives you some rectangle matrix with some duplicate columns. Just delete duplicate columns until you end up with a square matrix. This is the character table of $G/N$.